# Will scipy.interpolate.griddata correctly interpolate values for longitude and latitude float coordinates?

Tags: geometry, scipy, geospatial, interpolation

Lets say, I have 3 `np.array`s of float values in Python: `latitudes`, `longitudes` and `values`. I want to interpolate some values for coordinates that are not in the `latitude` and `longitude` arrays. I can use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` for that and it works just fine.

However I recently started to wonder if `interpolate` works as I expected it to: Because it does not know the difference between an euclidean grid and the spherical nature of a latitude and longitude grid, it may calculate the interpolated values wrong, at least for the `linear`. (Because the distance between 2 coordinates at the poles maybe vastly different than the distance between two coordinates at the equator.)

I did take look at the documentation that can be found
[at the scipy site](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) but did not find information about the handling of not-equidistant transformations.

Is the differnce between the spherical and equidistant nature of the coordinates a problem for `scipy.interpolate.griddata`, or is it irrelevant?

Comment: This looks as if it would be reasonably easy to test. Have you tested it ?

Comment: Tests take time, asking a question on a question-asking site does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`griddata` assumes Euclidean distance measure, so you have the usual sphere-to-plane map projection problems.

Scipy 0.11.0 has tools for interpolation of data on a sphere: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectSphereBivariateSpline.html

This works for rectilinear lat/lon grids.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [Slerp (spherical linear interpolation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp), which is a way to interpolate linearly on a sphere using [quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). There is a [quaternion dtype for numpy](https://github.com/martinling/numpy_quaternion) implemented as an add-on which would allow you to implement slerp in python efficiently. [Here](http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/doc2/quat.html) is also a library implemeting slerp.